# Too many alerts generated in for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I am trying to erase a wine for a json wine list and I want to pop an alert if the wine doesn't exist in json file. But the alert pops up for every i in the list. Can't think of a way to make it be done with if statement before it goes to else.

```
function slettVin(){
    var slettInput = document.getElementById('slettInput');
    var slettInput_v = slettInput.value;
    for(wine=0; wine<dataHent.wines.length; wine++){
        if (dataHent.wines[wine].catalog == slettInput_v){
            dataHent.wines.splice(wine,1);
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST","writeWine.php",false);
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            request.send("wines="+JSON.stringify(dataHent));
            fjernDiv();
            spesieltValg();
            slettInput.value ='';
            break;
        }
        else {
            alert('This wine doesnt exist');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell if the wine doesn't exist until you get through the whole loop. Use a variable to tell if you found the wine.

```js
var dataHent = {
  wines: [{
    catalog: "aaa"
  }, {
    catalog: "bbb"
  }, {
    catalog: "ccc"
  }]
};

function slettVin() {
  var slettInput = document.getElementById('slettInput');
  var slettInput_v = slettInput.value;
  var wine_found = false;
  for (wine = 0; wine < dataHent.wines.length; wine++) {
    if (dataHent.wines[wine].catalog == slettInput_v) {
      dataHent.wines.splice(wine, 1);
      alert("Wine found, sending AJAX");
      slettInput.value = '';
      wine_found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!wine_found) {
    alert('This wine doesnt exist');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="slettInput" type="text">
<button onclick="slettVin()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Sorry Barmar,but its not working. I thought about flaging also. Keeps popping up.Tks for your time though!

Comment: I was missing a `}`, does that help?

Comment: I just tested my code, it works. If you type "aaa" it alerts found, if you type zzz it alerts doesn't exist.

Comment: Jepp it is working. Tks for your time m8. And i couldnt understand why flaging wasnt working!!!